# Слушатель для кнопок

Tags: android

Есть 9 кнопок на активности. Для начала пытаюсь для трех кнопок сделать слушатель, который через id кнопки будет применять один и тот же метод (а после метода каждая кнопка будет открывать отдельное активити новое). Так вот решила сделать через switch. Но проблема в том что по нажатию на кнопки вращение срабатывает только со второго раза. Т.е. нажала на кнопку первый раз ничего не произошло, а второй раз наживаю уже вращает. И так для всех трех кнопок. Почему?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Animation rotateAnimation = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        // устанавливаем один обработчик для всех кнопок
        final ImageButton imgBtnAlphabet = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnAlphabet);
        final ImageButton imgBtnNumber = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnNumber);
        final ImageButton imgBtnPhone = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnPhone);

        imgBtnAlphabet.setOnClickListener(this);
        imgBtnNumber.setOnClickListener(this);
        imgBtnPhone.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void rotate(View v) {
        rotateAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotate);
        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                view.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.imgBtnAlphabet:
                rotate(findViewById(R.id.imgBtnAlphabet));
                break;
            case R.id.imgBtnNumber:
                rotate(findViewById(R.id.imgBtnNumber));
                break;
            case R.id.imgBtnPhone:
                rotate(findViewById(R.id.imgBtnPhone));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё дело в том, что вы лишний слушатель нажатий повесили в методе rotate. Он там просто не нужен. Именно из-за него у вас анимация срабатывает после второго нажатия, ибо 1 раз нажав вы вешаете случатель, запускающий анимацию. Т.е. метод rotate должен так выглядеть:

```
public void rotate(View v) {
    rotateAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotate);
    view.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
}
```